# Can you bridge a basic mesh wifi (e.g. google wifi) system with a separate wireless bridge?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-bridge, ubiquiti, google-wifi

I currently have one house with a mesh Wi-Fi system (Google Wi-Fi).  I am adding a back-house that is too far to reach with just mesh access points alone.

I would like to maintain the Google Wi-Fi setup in the primary house as it.  Ideally I would like to introduce one or more additional mesh-units to the back house.

Could I maintain continuity of the mesh-wifi network across both houses by using a standard wireless bridge (e.g.  Ubiquiti LocoM5 Bridge Kit) between one mesh-unit in the primary house and one mesh-unit in the secondary house? (See illustration)

From what I have read, a wireless bridge is equivalent to running an Ethernet cable.  If that is absolutely true, this should work.  But I haven't tried it myself and lack expertise in this domain.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Did this work for you? Thinking of doing the same.

Comment: @jonalport yeah it works. using it now.  i have two tp-link cpe510 units that serve as a bridge

Comment: Could you use the same wifi name / password & automatically switch when moving between houses ? Or did you need to create/configure 2 wifis on connected devices?

Comment: @StefanRogin yes i use the same wifi name and password. it works extremely well.  I can walk my laptop from one building to the other while on a video call without it dropping for even a split second --- it seamlessly transfers.  Pretty sweet.  From the mesh wifi stand point, it as if the two wifi points are connected via ethernet.  Note that I use "Google Wifi" not "Nest Wifi".  Nest Wifi i think only have a single ethernet port which could impose a limitation depending on what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should work, as long as the Google AP has an Ethernet-port to connect a Ethernet cable (the one you want to connect to the WLAN bridge). In layman's terms an AP works more or less like a switch where you can connect wireless and wired devices (as long as it has an Ethernet port).

Make sure you don't run more then one router device or disable the routing functionality often called "bridge mode" (unless you know how to configure multiple routers on a single LAN).